# Proving a possible number theoretic hypothesis

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

Suppose we have the following relations:

$$|y_i-x_i|<c, \\ |y_i-x_j| \geq c, \quad i > j \\ s.t \; \;  0 <  x_n\leq...\leq x_1 \\ \quad \; \;  0 < y_n \leq...\leq y_1 $$

assume WLOG $y_i \geq x_i, \forall i$ and $y_i$, $x_i$ are strictly positive as mentioned above.
We also have to enforce the following i.e., only the below mentioned convex combinations are allowed:

$$|\sum_{i=1}^n a_iy_i - \sum_{i=1}^n b_ix_i| < c, \\ s.t \; \sum_{i=1}^n a_i=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i = 1, \quad b_i,c_i \geq 0$$

Define two fractions as following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{x_i} = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{x_i} }}, \quad \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{y_i} = \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{y_i} }}$$

I want to show that if we enforce all the above condtions then we cannot have that:

$$|p-q| > c$$

This is easy to show for the case of a single term i.e, say:

$$ \frac{1}{x_i} = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_i} }} = \frac{1}{x_i}, \quad \frac{1}{y_j} = \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y_j} }} = \frac{1}{y_j}$$

Now assuming our $|p-q| > c$ hypothesis is false we assume that the admissible convex combination $b_i=1$ associated with $x_i$ and $a_i=1$ associated with $y_j$. Now if $y_j-x_i \geq c$, then we also have $|a_jy_j - b_ix_i| = |y_j-x_j| \geq c $ which is a contradiction to our enforced constraint earlier.

QUESTION: How to generalize this for the general $p,q$ as defined above i.e., a general convex combination? Or is there a case where this hypothesis is false?

Comment: Feel free to add appropriate titles or tags.